# MS SQL OrderBy group of set criteria

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I need to translate this Linq OrderBy statement into SQL:

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Gender == "f" && x.IsCouple == 0)
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.ApprovalRejectedDate)
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.Id);
```

Simply having:

```
ORDER BY x.Gender, x.IsCouple, x.ApprovalRejectedDate, x.Id
```

returns a different order as the first group of criteria need to be matched together.

Any ideas how I can do this in SQL?

Comment: Your first `OrderByDescending` should be `Where`. Isn't it ?

Comment: If you debug this and hover over list then you should see the sql generated by entity framework.  You can copy it out and examine what it is doing.

Comment: Not necessarily Habib, because I still want to show all genders and having that statement in a where clause will restrict this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order by
 case when x.Gender = 'f' and x.IsCouple = 0 then 1 else 0 end,
 x.ApplrovalRejectedDate desc,
 x.Id desc
```